# web3.eth.blockNumber is undefined

Tags: web3js, blockchain

1. I have a running blockchain on 128.230.208.73 .
2. I have created local-node on my system using following commands:

   ```
   geth --datadir bkc_data --networkid 89992018 --bootnodes enode://9b46f0691dd12ae427adde13988a56e4691ddcba52f7d6f32d4a4129c709196d1ade96985a9522aa73cac957b666b1f41d69ebceae350643ae83217196e6240d@128.230.208.73:30301 --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi=eth,web3,net,personal,ssh,db,debug --nodiscover console 2>console.log
   ```
3. Inside geth console, I am adding peer using command:

   ```
   admin.addPeer("enode://62bceb7302bf4368858a15c408ab8d57a263cb590fb4a6ccb588a1ecad42266772370c5d6b3cdaa1a1284c80f6f3fe959ba1453761482fbcc9920a4c2c7099ab@128.230.208.73:30303")
   ```
4. Now in the same directory, I have abc.js which has following code:

   ```
   var Web3 = require('web3');
   var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

   console.log("block number => "+web3.eth.blockNumber);
   ```
5. Now, in terminal, I am running `node abc.js` from same directory but I am getting `block number => undefined`

Kindly let me know, where I am making mistake.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Note: (Let me know if you need more information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead to make an async call as following:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(error, result){ 
  if (!error)
    console.log("block number => "result)
});
```

Comment: I am getting following error: There is not missing parenthesis. web3.eth.getBlockNumber(callback(error, result){ if(!error) cosole.log(result) })
                                              ^SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
)

Comment: Could you  please confirm once that my (1) geth Command & (2)Http-provider statements are totally correct or not ?
Thank You.

Comment: Your answer is working. Just need to replace 'callback' with 'function'.
Could you please let me know, how can I execute a 'sendTransaction' through simple javascript file(same as above).
Thank You.